# emberjs 1.0.0pre4 how do you pass a context object to a resource "...Index" route?

Tags: ember.js

In a simple ember application I have a single resource ('detail') with an index template. In the application index template I have a button which calls `transitionTo('detail',obj)` on the index controller, where `obj` is the content item that was clicked. This passes `obj` as the `model` argument to my `DetailRouter.setupController` function, but **NOT** to my `DetailIndexRouter.setupController` function. How can I pass my context object all the way through to the 'leaf' route?

I have seen a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063066/transitiontoroute-context-passes-context-base-route-not-to-the-route-reque), but I am working with a dynamic segment in the route.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw8Q3/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the model for the `DetailIndexRouter`, override it's model hook and then use `modelFor('detail')` to access the content item from the parent route. So for example:

```
App.DetailIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor("detail");
  }
});
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw8Q3/2/