# Trouble access dynamic segment in Ember.js Object Route

Tags: ember.js

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with the accessing the dynamic segment from the route.

I have a Keyword model.  When showing the collection of Keywords, I want the path to read `/keywords`.  When accessing a single Keyword, I want the path to read `/keyword/:KEYWORD_ID`.  By convention, Ember wants you to do the following…

```
this.resource('keywords', { path: '/keywords' }, function() {

    this.route('new', { path: '/new' });
    this.resource('keyword', { path: '/keyword/:keyword_id' }, function() {

        this.route('edit');

    });

});
```

In order to achieve the above behavior, I'm doing the following...

```
this.resource('keywords', { path: '/keywords' }, function() {

    this.route('new', { path: '/new' });

});

this.resource('keyword', { path: '/keyword/:keyword_id' }, function() {

    this.route('edit');

});
```

However, when using the second approach, the route for KeywordIndex (i.e. the single Keyword Object), the `params` object is null, and the content on screen is blank.

```
App.KeywordIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {

            return App.Keyword.find(params.keyword_id);

    },

    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

        this.render({outlet: 'page'});

    }

});
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: As a follow-up, I've used the approach describer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609757/emberjs-1-0-0pre4-how-do-you-pass-a-context-object-to-a-resource-index-rout).  However, this works for all cases, except for when some directly access the Keyword Detail view by URL (i.e. types ../keyword/ID into their browser and hits enter).  In this case, the screen shows the data for second, and then disappears.  When looking at the model, you can see all the data was erased for object (ID).  Strange.

Comment: Do you know that the model hook is just executed when your Route is entered via URL? It is difficult to tell, what the problem is, because you do not talk about how you transition between your Routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  The issue was in our API for this specific object.  The best approach, for those considering this routing pattern is as follows...

```
this.resource('keywords', { path: '/keywords' }, function() {

    this.route('new', { path: '/new' });

});

this.resource('keyword', { path: '/keyword/:keyword_id' }, function() {

    this.route('edit');

});
```

You would then access the model in your controller like this...

```
App.KeywordIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {

        return this.modelFor("keyword");

    },

    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

        this.render({outlet: 'page'});

    }

});
```